# Select Columns only if greater than 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have about 70 total columns that will have either a 1 or a 0 in the column.  I'm trying to only Select the columns that have more than 0.  What's the best way to do that please? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "column that have more than 0"?   Do you mean, if the sum of all the rows is more than 0?   And why did you provide a link to an empty SQL fiddle?

Comment: Not clear.  You need to add more or this will get closed.

Comment: This smells like dynamic SQL, which I recommend staying very far away from.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was trying to get SQL Fiddle to work but couldn't.  I have added a picture of what a sample of my data currently looks like.  I would like to only pull the columns that are > 0,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but SQL really doesn't have a good mechanism for selecting columns based on their value.  However, if you convert the columns to rows using `PIVOT` then you can use a basic `WHERE` clause to filter the rows.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I think this will get me what I need.